# Flutter API Fetch and Sending Data from One screen to another screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

When I am logged in through the API I am getting the value **User_id** which **I am able to print on console, but I want to use it on another screen**.
So how can I send the data to another screen?
// First Screen

```
Future postMethod() async {
var api = Uri.parse("https://demo.likemyfiles.com/DS/api/auth/otp");
Map mapeddate = {
  'phone': _phone.text,
  'otp': _otp.text,
};
final response = await http.post(api, body: mapeddate);
print(response.body);
var res = json.decode(response.body);
print(res['user_id']); 
Navigator.pushNamed(context, StartActivity.id);   //here i want to send the User_Id
}
```

//Second Screen (Start Activity) in this screen there is a function FetchData where i want to use the data

```
Future fetchdata() async {
var url = await http.get(Uri.parse(
    "http://demo.likemyfiles.com/DS/api/api_supervisor/supervisor/3")); //Instead of 3 i want 
  to use the User_Id variable
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You should try to declare **constructor** the first page accept the id and push this id to second page or screen like this below code is first page

```
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => ABC.withId(
    id,
  ),
 ),
)
```

the create constructor inside second page screen

```
class ABC extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ABCState createState() => _ABCState();

  var id;
  
  ABC.withId(String uid) {
    id = uid;
   
  }
}
```

accept your id inside widget using **widget.id**