# How to get particular field name by matching to JSON responses in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, httpresponse

I have two types of APIs one which returns a response of **all jobs posted** and the second one which returns response of **user applied jobs**. For this, I'm first storing all jobs responses in the list and jobID from applied jobs in int var then applied the for a loop when index matches the jobID it gives us JobName.

this method will return All Jobs' resonse.

```
List<String> allJobsList = [];
  Future<List<dynamic>> getAllJobsData() async {
    String url = 'https://hospitality92.com/api/jobsbycategory/All';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
    allJobsList.add(json.decode(response.body)['jobs'].toString()); // here all jobs response added to list
    
    return json.decode(response.body)['jobs'];
  }
```

this method returns user-applied jobs.

```
Future<List<dynamic>> getUSerAppliedJobs() async {
    String url = 'https://hospitality92.com/api/getappliedjobs/10'; // 10 is userID
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
    return json.decode(response.body)['jobs']; // this returns user applied jobs
  }
```

These two methods are used to get job names by matching jobID.
Here I'll use a future builder to get a response and show it in listview.

```
ListView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        var jobID = int.parse(snapshot.data![index]['job_id']) ;                      
                        var getJobName ="";
                        for (int i = 0; i <= allJobsList.length; i++) {
                          if (i == jobID) {
                            var jobName = allJobsList.elementAt(i-2);
                            getJobName = jobName;
                            print(getJobName); 
                            break;
                          }
                        }},
                    ),
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @stacktrace2234 as mentioned in the title, basically I'm trying to get a job name for this I've to explain the whole situation above

Comment: I don't really understand from where you wanna get the job name... You pasted here some codes where you make the fetches but it does not add any value to the question. We don't have to know from where you got the data if you have it. We have to know how the data looks like. How do you try to get the value you expect, what does it give back instead...

Comment: You want to get selected user jobName Correct?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil yes sir selected user applied jobName

Comment: @UsamaHafeez refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68494291/13997210) hope it help to you.

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil sir this answer is about sending data from one screen to another via the constructor, but I want to fetch jobName on that page only,

Comment: yes this is correct if you cant understand this solution I will give answer of your question tonight I understand your problem and solved it to via constructor give  me the time

Comment: are you change appliedjob/10 userid API? If yor are get selected user applied job on new screen so first add user id to your all job API

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil 10 is the userid, after I'll get the JobName  , I'll make it dynamic, for now I'm testing it for user 10