# How to send a value to several screens in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and I'm making an application with a `CRUD`, in the home should appear each user and that when touching it should send to other screens the `id` of the user to be able the query.
I have already tried to send the data to the other screens with a `Class` and `Streams` but I have not been able to do it, I show an example where I am testing:

HomePage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text('Home'),
     ),
     body: Center(
       child: ListView(
         padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
         children: [
           Row(
             children: [
               Text('User 1'),
               Expanded(child: Column()),
               ElevatedButton(
                 child: Text('Send id'),
                 onPressed: () {
                   Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'pageOne');
                 },
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

[image]

PageOne

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageOne extends StatefulWidget {
  PageOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageOneState createState() => _PageOneState();
}

class _PageOneState extends State<PageOne> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('PageOne'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Id: ##'),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Send id to page two'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'pageTwo');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: are you print Id on console? refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68494291/13997210)

Comment: are you try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68494291/13997210) if any problem let me know

Comment: You send data but don't receive it. Read here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Comment: I already tried to do it with your answer and it worked, but being several screens, in my case I would have to send and return the id between screens to be able to maintain the value and to make the consultations, by means of the `Navigator`. I do not know if it would be right or if the code is clean to do it that way, what do you recommend? I hope I have explained well what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to pass your data down in the widget tree**

Home

```
Navigator.push(
 context, 
 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PageOne(id: YOUR INT ID)),
);
```

Page1:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageOne extends StatefulWidget {

  final int id;

  PageOne({Key? key, required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageOneState createState() => _PageOneState();
}

class _PageOneState extends State<PageOne> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('PageOne'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Id: ' + id.toString()),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Send id to page two'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => Page2(id: YOUR INT ID)),);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Page2: Same as Page1