# how to pass data from one screen to another screen with pushNamed in FLutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to pass data of textbox controller from one screen to another screen using pushNamed, So how can i pass the Data?

Here is the method which Navigate the Screen. As Bellow in page one.

```
@override
  void validateOtpSuccess() {
    Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(Constants.ROUTE_CHANGE_PASSWORD);
  }
```

And I want to get data on change password screen, so how i can access the data to change password screen?

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68494291/13997210)  hope it's helpful to you. But one thing I'm using `Navigator.push()` method

Answer (score 0):

In the first page (assuming `data` is a `String`):

```
final result = await Navigator.pushNamed<String?>(context, '/change_password_page', arguments: data);
```

In your `onGenerateRoute` method:

```
Route? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  ...
  switch (settings.name) {
    ...
    case '/change_password_page':
      final data = settings.arguments as String?;
      return MaterialPageRoute<String?>(
        builder: (context) => ChangePasswordPage(arguments: data!),
      );
```

In your `ChangePasswordPage` widget:

```
class ChangePasswordPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String data;

  const ChangePasswordPage({required this.data, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChangePasswordPageState createState() => _ChangePasswordPageState();
}
...
Navigator.pop<String?>(context, _newPassword);
```