# Flutter - Select list with display and return value

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible in flutter use select list with display and return value

For example:

from this web service https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

**id = value in select list, name = display value in select list**

If user select **Leanne Graham** I need get id of Leanne Graham (1) and send  to database. If select **Ervin Howell** need get value (2).

Comment: do you want a dropdown list(Select list) which returns a value when selecting a option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68494291/13997210) for that.

You want to create One class for Your all list and call [this](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) url for that

Your All list API call

```
 Future<List<dynamic>> getJobsData() async {
    String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

Your All list Widget:

```
 Expanded(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
          future: getJobsData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                   itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    var name = snapshot.data![index]['name'];
                    var email = snapshot.data![index]['email'];
                    var id = snapshot.data![index]['id'];
                    return Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green.shade300),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Text(id.toString()),
                            title: Text(name),
                            subtitle: Text(email),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Your result screen for all data -> [image]

Then you create sent Id to that name to next class for selected user and use [this](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1) url

you pass above selected user id [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210) formate