# Flutter calling specific element from API

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I'm trying to call API from this site https://workshops.xposure.ae/wp-json/wp/task/v1/photographer. Now I get a list of names. I want to call all the elements assigned to a single name. My question is how to display all the details of the specific user such as photographer, total_schedule and display all schedule_details.

Here are my files

Api request

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/tasks/models/tasks.dart';



class TaskApi {
  static var client2 = http.Client();
  static Future<Task?> fetchTasks() async {
    var response = await client2.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://workshops.xposure.ae/wp-json/wp/task/v1/photographer'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonString = response.body;
      print(jsonString);
      return taskFromJson(jsonString);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Task View

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/instance_manager.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/events/views/event_details.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/events/views/event_tile.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/home/controllers/home_controller.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/tasks/controllers/tasks_controller.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/tasks/views/task_details.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/tasks/views/task_tile.dart';

class TaskView extends StatelessWidget {
  final TasksController tasksController = Get.put(TasksController());
  HomeController get homeController => Get.find<HomeController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Obx(() {
              if (tasksController.isLoading.value)
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ));
              else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: tasksController.task.value!.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TaskDetails(task: tasksController.task.value!.data![index]))
                            );
                          },
                          child: TaskTile(tasksController.task.value!.data![index]));
                    });
              }
            }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Task Model

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

Task taskFromJson(String str) => Task.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String taskToJson(Task data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Task {
  Task({
    required this.data,
  });

  List<Datum>? data;

  factory Task.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Task(
    data: json["data"] == null ? null : List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": data == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(data!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    required this.photographer,
    required this.totalSchedule,
    required this.scheduleDetails,
  });

  String photographer;
  int totalSchedule;
  List<ScheduleDetail>? scheduleDetails;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
    photographer: json["photographer"] == null ? null : json["photographer"],
    totalSchedule: json["total_schedule"] == null ? null : json["total_schedule"],
    scheduleDetails: json["schedule_details"] == null ? null : List<ScheduleDetail>.from(json["schedule_details"].map((x) => ScheduleDetail.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "photographer": photographer == null ? null : photographer,
    "total_schedule": totalSchedule == null ? null : totalSchedule,
    "schedule_details": scheduleDetails == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(scheduleDetails!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class ScheduleDetail {
  ScheduleDetail({
    required this.date,
    required this.startTime,
    required this.endTime,
    required this.taskname,
    required this.location,
  });

  Date? date;
  StartTime? startTime;
  EndTime? endTime;
  Taskname? taskname;
  Location? location;

  factory ScheduleDetail.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ScheduleDetail(
    date: json["date"] == null ? null : dateValues.map[json["date"]],
    startTime: json["start_time"] == null ? null : startTimeValues.map[json["start_time"]],
    endTime: json["end_time"] == null ? null : endTimeValues.map[json["end_time"]],
    taskname: json["taskname"] == null ? null : tasknameValues.map[json["taskname"]],
    location: json["location"] == null ? null : locationValues.map[json["location"]],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "date": date == null ? null : dateValues.reverse![date],
    "start_time": startTime == null ? null : startTimeValues.reverse![startTime],
    "end_time": endTime == null ? null : endTimeValues.reverse![endTime],
    "taskname": taskname == null ? null : tasknameValues.reverse![taskname],
    "location": location == null ? null : locationValues.reverse![location],
  };
}

enum Date { THE_08022022, THE_09022022, THE_10022022 }

final dateValues = EnumValues({
  "08-02-2022": Date.THE_08022022,
  "09-02-2022": Date.THE_09022022,
  "10-02-2022": Date.THE_10022022
});

enum EndTime { THE_2030, THE_1130, THE_1240, THE_1430 }

final endTimeValues = EnumValues({
  "11:30": EndTime.THE_1130,
  "12:40": EndTime.THE_1240,
  "14:30": EndTime.THE_1430,
  "20:30": EndTime.THE_2030
});

enum Location { GALLERY_X, AUDITORIUM, WORKSHOP_2, PORTFOLIO_REVIEW_AREA }

final locationValues = EnumValues({
  "Auditorium": Location.AUDITORIUM,
  "GalleryX": Location.GALLERY_X,
  "Portfolio Review Area": Location.PORTFOLIO_REVIEW_AREA,
  "Workshop 2": Location.WORKSHOP_2
});

enum StartTime { THE_1900, THE_1100, THE_1400 }

final startTimeValues = EnumValues({
  "11:00": StartTime.THE_1100,
  "14:00": StartTime.THE_1400,
  "19:00": StartTime.THE_1900
});

enum Taskname { PRIVATE_EVENT, OPENING_SPEECH, WORKSHOP, PORTFOLIO_REVIEW }

final tasknameValues = EnumValues({
  "Opening Speech": Taskname.OPENING_SPEECH,
  "Portfolio Review": Taskname.PORTFOLIO_REVIEW,
  "Private Event": Taskname.PRIVATE_EVENT,
  "Workshop": Taskname.WORKSHOP
});

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String>? reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String>? get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

Task Controller

```
import 'package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_types.dart';
import 'package:get/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_controllers.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/services/api_request.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/tasks/models/tasks.dart';

class TasksController extends GetxController {

  final isLoading = true.obs;
  final task = Rxn<Task>();
  // final taskSchedule = Rxn<ScheduleDetail>();

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    await fetchEvents();
    super.onInit();
  }

  fetchEvents() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var response = await TaskApi.fetchTasks();
      if (response != null) {
        task.value = response;
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }




  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {}

}
```

Task Tile

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/home/controllers/home_controller.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/tasks/models/tasks.dart';



class TaskTile extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeController get homeController => Get.find<HomeController>();

  final Datum task;
  const TaskTile(this.task);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
            ),
            color: Colors.black12,
            elevation: 2,
            child: Column(
              // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Column(
                  // alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                        task.photographer
                    ),
                    Text(
                      task.totalSchedule.toString()
                    ),
                    Text(
                      task.scheduleDetails.toString()
                    )

                    // Text(
                    //   homeController.user.value!.name
                    // )

                  ],
                ),
              ],
            )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Instead of displaying a list of photographers, I would like to display single photographer  details as mentioned above mostly focusing on displaying nested data in schedule_details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you.

Your API call function:

```
Future<List<dynamic>> getInfoData() async {
    String url = 'https://workshops.xposure.ae/wp-json/wp/task/v1/photographer';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
     return json.decode(response.body)['data'];
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
          future: getInfoData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length ,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    var name = snapshot.data![index]['photographer'];
                    var totalSchedule =
                        snapshot.data![index]['total_schedule'];
                    var date1 = snapshot.data![index]['schedule_details'][0]
                        ['date'];
                    var date2 = snapshot.data![index]['schedule_details'][1]
                        ['date'];
                    var startTime1 = snapshot.data![index]
                        ['schedule_details'][0]['start_time'];
                    var startTime2 = snapshot.data![index]
                        ['schedule_details'][1]['start_time'];
                    var endTime1 = snapshot.data![index]['schedule_details']
                        [0]['end_time'];
                    var endTime2 = snapshot.data![index]['schedule_details']
                        [1]['end_time'];
                    var taskNeme1 = snapshot.data![index]
                        ['schedule_details'][0]['taskname'];
                    var taskNeme2 = snapshot.data![index]
                        ['schedule_details'][1]['taskname'];
                    var location1 = snapshot.data![index]
                        ['schedule_details'][0]['location'];
                    var location2 = snapshot.data![index]
                        ['schedule_details'][1]['location'];
                    return Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green.shade300),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          ExpansionTile(
                            title: Text(name),
                            leading: Text(totalSchedule.toString()),
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Schedule Details 1',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              ListTile(
                                title: Text('Task Name - $taskNeme1'),
                                subtitle: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text('Date - $date1'),
                                    Text('Start Date - $startTime1'),
                                    Text('End Date - $endTime1'),
                                    Text('Location - $location1'),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Schedule Details 2',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              ListTile(
                                title: Text('Task Name - $taskNeme2'),
                                subtitle: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text('Date - $date2'),
                                    Text('Start Date - $startTime2'),
                                    Text('End Date - $endTime2'),
                                    Text('Location - $location2'),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            }
            return Center(
              child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Your result screen for all list -> [image: Image1]

Your result screen for selected user schedule info -> [image: Image2]

If you display selected name data then create other url and pass their name or id of that name and pass this id or name like  my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68494291/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210)

Refer ExpansionTile [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html)

Comment: So in the code I've posted I managed to do the same thing. However, my question is to filter the list to one specific name and display nested elements that are assigned under scheduled_details.

Comment: @Quentinio please check my updated answer hope its help to you. Just click on card/name of user and display other info. I have used `ExpansionTile()` widget

Comment: Thank you, that does work but is not using model class. By hard coding indexes [0, 1], it's not flexible when there are more elements than 2.

Comment: If your problem is solved then accept(mark) my answer