# flutter expansion panel listView Builder

Tags: flutter, listview, expansion

a beginner in a field, I have this code that works, but there is an error in the case of clicking
When I click on any card, all cards also open. I want to open a card that I just click on

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:english_club/data/im.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';


class Novals extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NovalsState createState()
  {
    return _NovalsState();
  }
}

class _NovalsState extends State<Novals> {
  bool _expanded = false;
  var _test = "Full Screen";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: storys.length,

        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: ExpansionPanelList(
                    animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                    children: [
                      ExpansionPanel(
                          headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(storys[index]["name"], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                            );
                          },
                          body:ListTile(
                            title: Text(storys[index]["lines"],style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                          ),
                        isExpanded: _expanded,
                        canTapOnHeader: true,
                      ),
                    ],
                    dividerColor: Colors.grey,
                    expansionCallback: (panelIndex, isExpanded) {
                      _expanded = !_expanded;
                      setState(() {

                      });
                    },

              ),
             ),
                ),
            ]
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to solve it, but I could not aim for the code to display the name of the story, and when the user clicks on it, the whole story appears

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70506029/13997210) your answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter calling specific element from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70505647/flutter-calling-specific-element-from-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should remove the `SingleChildScrollView` as the `ListView` child. `ListView.builder` is enough to provide scrolling to your `Scaffold`.

For the main issue, you should split each item to a separate `Widget` with its own `_expanded` state. This will make your UI much faster, the widgets will expand separately and the whole screen won't have to reload after each item's `setState()`.

Example code:

```
class Novals extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NovalsState createState()
  {
    return _NovalsState();
  }
}

class _NovalsState extends State<Novals> {
  var _test = "Full Screen";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: storys.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return StoryWidget(story: storys[index]);
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StoryWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> story;
  const StoryWidget({Key? key, required this.story}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StoryWidgetState createState() => _StoryWidgetState();
}

class _StoryWidgetState extends State<StoryWidget> {  
bool _expanded = false;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              color: Colors.green,
              child: ExpansionPanelList(
                animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                children: [
                  ExpansionPanel(
                    headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(widget.story["name"], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                      );
                    },
                    body:ListTile(
                      title: Text(widget.story["lines"],style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    ),
                    isExpanded: _expanded,
                    canTapOnHeader: true,
                  ),
                ],
                dividerColor: Colors.grey,
                expansionCallback: (panelIndex, isExpanded) {
                  _expanded = !_expanded;
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]
    );
  }
}
```

P/s: It's a good practice to put your `story` into a model class using `jsonDecode()` instead of using `Map` directly. It would help you avoid bugs and better maintenance in the long term

Comment: It works thanks you saved me, can you give me more related articles on this method

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the same `_expanded` variable for items in your `ListView`.

```dart
class _NovalsState extends State<Novals> {
  bool _expanded = false;

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

So when your `itemBuilder` is called in the `ListView`, it uses the same `_expanded` value for every item.

**Solution:**

Move the `_expanded` variable from the `State` to inside the body `itemBuilder` function.

```dart
class _NovalsState extends State<Novals> {

  var _test = "Full Screen";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: storys.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            bool _expanded = false;
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(children: [
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: ExpansionPanelList(
                      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                      children: [
                        ExpansionPanel(
                          headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                storys[index]["name"],
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          body: ListTile(
                            title: Text(storys[index]["lines"],
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                          ),
                          isExpanded: _expanded,
                          canTapOnHeader: true,
                        ),
                      ],
                      dividerColor: Colors.grey,
                      expansionCallback: (panelIndex, isExpanded) {
                        _expanded = !_expanded;
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Checkout [Dart's Lexical Scope](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lexical-scope)

Answer (score 0):

I demonstrate how to use the callback function to set the toggle state of the panel.  I display a list of comments in the ExpansionPanelList.  Each comment in the list is mapped as a comment type for the expansion panel. The expansion panel uses the isExpanded value to determine if it is collapsed or expanded.  The expansionPanelList call back expansionCallback is invoke on an collapse or expand event toggling the value.

```
 class Comment {
  final String title;
  final String body;
  bool isExpanded = false;

  Comment(this.title, this.body);
}
   ExpansionPanelList(
                        expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
                          setState(() {
                            _commentsList[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                          });
                        },
                        children: _commentsList
                            .map<ExpansionPanel>((Comment comment) {
                          return ExpansionPanel(
                            headerBuilder:
                                (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                              return const ListTile(title: Text("Comments"));
                            },
                            body: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(comment.body),
                              ],
                            ),
                            isExpanded: comment.isExpanded,
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      )
```