# Any idea on how I should pass my data from one page to another in flutter?

Tags: flutter

This is my app scheme [image]

I need to access Page 2 from the edit button on Page 3, but I have no idea how I should pass the required data on Page 2? (The order JSON structure is different from Menu, even though some fields are the same).

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68494291/13997210) answer for sending data to one screen to other or refer official documentation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I did that actually when sending data from Page 1 to Page 2, but the problem is the data on Page 3 doesn't contain the required data on Page 2 (Page 3 only contains the Order data, not Menu data)